# How to read a localfile in JavaScript with XMLHttpRequest on localhost?

Tags: javascript, file, firefox, xmlhttprequest, localhost

I am working on a small web application to be run on an Apache server locally.
For this little project I have to read a file on a network (shared) drive, but I have been stuck on trying to read a local file that isnt in the server-root for a while now. I have tried lots of different things but nothing seems to work, if anybody has experienced this issues or has an idea please feel free to inform me.

This is the part of my JavaScript that reads the header of the file to see the size of the file.

```
    var fileURL = "file:///c:/Users/Billy/test.csv";
    var totalFileSize = 0;


    sizeRequest.open('HEAD', fileURL, true);
    sizeRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
            if (this.status === 200) {
                totalFileSize = this.getResponseHeader('content-length');
                alert('Total file size = ' + totalFileSize);
            }
        }
    };
    sizeRequest.send();
```

It works perfectly if the file is under the root of the server.

Another thing i found online that might help is adding these lines in a new users.js file in FireFox

```
user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "localfilelinks");
user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.sites", "http://localhost"); 
user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.checkloaduri.enabled", "allAccess");
```

Sadly this does not fix my problem.

To clearify:

```
Using a Apache server
Using http://localhost
Using FireFox
Trying to read a file from a local location(instead of server-root)
```

I have been stuck on this for some time so any help will be great,

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need backend code (like PHP) that reads the file and forwards it.

Comment: @ChrisG can you maybe give a small example or link to what you are saying, im unexperienced in PHP and has been a while since i did any coding.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php